# Create Airflow connections on Cloud Composer using gcloud CLI

Tags: airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create airflow connections on Cloud Composer using gcloud CLI.
I follow the document and run the following comment.
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#creating_new_airflow_connections

```
gcloud composer environments run my-env \
  --project my-project \
  --location asia-northeast1 \
  connections -- --add \
  --conn_id=my-conn-id \
  --conn_type=google_cloud_platform \
  --conn_extra '{"extra\__google\_cloud\_platform\__project": "my-project", \
  "extra\__google\_cloud\_platform\__key_path": "/home/airflow/gcs/data/keys/my-key.json", \
  "extra\__google\_cloud\_platform\__scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"}'

kubeconfig entry generated for asia-northeast1-my-env-44718514-gke.
Executing within the following kubectl namespace: default
W0525 22:51:11.244104   93234 flags.go:39] conn_extra is DEPRECATED and will be removed in
a future version. Use conn-extra instead.
W0525 22:51:11.244246   93234 flags.go:39] conn_extra is DEPRECATED and will be removed in
a future version. Use conn-extra instead.
W0525 22:51:11.244256   93234 flags.go:39] conn_extra is DEPRECATED and will be removed in
a future version. Use conn-extra instead.

[2019-05-25 14:51:13,215] {settings.py:176} INFO - setting.configure_orm():
Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800
[2019-05-25 14:51:13,598] {default_celery.py:80} WARNING - You have configured a
result_backend of redis://airflow-redis-service:6379/0, it is highly recommended to use an
alternative result_backend (i.e. a database).
[2019-05-25 14:51:13,600] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2019-05-25 14:51:13,680] {app.py:51} WARNING - Using default Composer Environment Variables.
Overrides have not been applied.
[2019-05-25 14:51:13,688] {configuration.py:516} INFO - Reading the config from
/etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2019-05-25 14:51:13,698] {configuration.py:516} INFO - Reading the config from 
/etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

The connection is successfully created but project ID, key file path and scope are empty. So the connection is invalid.

When I manually created, those properties are not empty. Am I missing something?

Composer image: composer-1.5.0-airflow-1.10.1

Comment: What version of Composer / Airflow are you using?

Comment: I am using composer-1.5.0-airflow-1.10.1

Comment: Does it work if you use a long line instead of the \-quoted newlines within the JSON text (and switch to `conn-extra` like the warning says)? Shell quoting is hell. Also I'd expect `__` to not need quoting, but if it does, quoting only one of the two underscores in `\__` seems unlikely to work.

Comment: the officials documents suggest to use backslash https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some syntax error on escaping quotation. This works fine.

```
$ CONNECTION_CREATE_COMMAND="gcloud composer environments run $COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT \
  --project $COMPOSER_PROJECT \
  --location ${COMPOSER_LOCATION} \
  connections -- --add \
  --conn_id=${CONN_ID_BASE}_${app}_${c} \
  --conn_type=google_cloud_platform \
  --conn_extra '{\"extra__google_cloud_platform__project\": \"${BQ_PROJECT}\", \
                 \"extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path\": \"${KEY_JSON_FILE_PATH}\", \
                 \"extra__google_cloud_platform__scope\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform\"}'"
$ eval $CONNECTION_CREATE_COMMAND
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to replicate it. When I run the following command the connection does get added with the extras field:

```
gcloud composer environments run my-env \
  --project my-project \
  --location europe-west1 \
  connections -- --add \
  --conn_id=my-conn-id \
  --conn_type=google_cloud_platform \
  --conn_extra='{"extra__google_cloud_platform__project": "my-project", "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path":"/tesf"}
```

Comment: it seems like running the command on console is fine. running this command from shell script is not working.